# How to apply IBM CPLEX to my iOS projects?

Tags: ios, swift, cplex

I am new to iOS development!
And I'm working on a project that deals with shift scheduling problems.
I was reading online paper and they mentioned that they used CPLEX to solve their linear programming problems.
So I'm wondering if there's anything that I have to know to run my scheduling constraints on CPLEX but get the results on Swift codes (XCode)?

Comment: What architecture, specifically, are you targeting?  You can see the supported platforms [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27019100).  As of the most current release (12.6.3), ARM is not supported, for example.

Comment: Would a client-server approach not be more appropriate? Let a server do the heavy lifting of solving the optimization problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you could try also is to use CPLEX in the cloud which would be called from IOS.

You can find an example at https://developer.ibm.com/docloud/blog/2016/03/17/docloud-and-bluemix-demo/

You can try that example on your smartphone and then have a look at how to.

regards

Comment: There is a wish about CPLEX in ARM at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=126844

Answer (score 0):

CPLEX offers some libraries written in C, C++.
Xcode allow the use of this kind of librairies so I think you'll be able to work with inside your Swift project.

Hope this helps !